# Multiplicar e Somar de acordo com o Dropdown

Tags: javascript

Nesse codigo a baixo ele faz o calculo de acordo com o checkbox mais eu não sei como fazer o terceiro campo funcionar. Esse terceiro campo só tem que multiplicar um valor pelo numero escolhido no dropdown,  mexendo o menos possível nesse código já existente

- Exemplo $Valor = 50; 
  $valor  x numero no dropdown e soma no valor total

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".valores1").change(function() {
        var total = 1000;
        total += $('input[class="valores1"]:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
            return tot + Number(el.value);
        }, 0);
        $('#total1').val(total.toFixed(2));        
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="opensans size13"><b>500,00 Ida e Volta?  
<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" name="choice" value="500" /><br/>

<span class="opensans size13"><b>200,00 Adcional?  
<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" name="choice" value="200" /><br/>
                                    
<span class="opensans size13"><b>50,00 Cadeira  X     
<select  class="valores1" name="cadeira" >
 <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>  //Fazer esse função funcionar
<br/>
                                    <br />                                    

<input type="text" size="6"  readonly="" name="total" id="total1" value="1000" /><br /><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegue o valor do item selecionado pelo id do select.

A propriedade  `..selectedIndex].value` - obtém o value do item selecionado no momento

`var e = document.getElementById("valores2");
 var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".valores1").change(function() {
    var total = 1000;
    total += $('input[class="valores1"]:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
      return tot + Number(el.value);
    }, 0);
        
    var e = document.getElementById("valores2");
    var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    total=total+(itemSelecionado*50);
    $('#total1').val(total.toFixed(2));        
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="opensans size13"><b>500,00 Ida e Volta?  
<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" name="choice" value="500" /><br/>

<span class="opensans size13"><b>200,00 Adcional?  
<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" name="choice" value="200" /><br/>
                                    
<span class="opensans size13"><b>50,00 Cadeira  X     
<select id="valores2"  class="valores1" name="cadeira" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>  //Fazer esse função funcionar
<br/>
                                    <br />                                    

<input type="text" size="6"  readonly="" name="total" id="total1" value="1000" /><br /><br />
```